# Ionic 5 action sheet text not accept transloco

Tags: ionic-framework, transloco

I am using action sheet and transloco translate plugin in my ionic 5 angular app.

When I use transloco on text the APP is considering as string.

```
buttons: [{
    text: "{{'channel.edit' | transloco}}",
    icon: 'create-outline',
```

[image]

So what should be the correct way to pass the translated text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use TranslateService to translate any variables 
alertTitle;

```
 constructor(translate: TranslateService) {
    translateService.get('channel.edit').subscribe(
      value => {
        this.alertTitle = value;
      }
    )
```

then

```
buttons: [{
    text: this.alertTitle,
    icon: 'create-outline',
```

Comment: Thanks @Neha .. In my case I had to use constructor(private translocoService: TranslocoService ) { }    this.others_close = this.translocoService.translate('others.close');